# Invoke windows service methods programmatically from a REST application(web api)?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, windows-services, ipc

I have a REST API created using web API c# and I need to programmatically invoke a method inside of a windows service running on the same box.

I have done some reading on the topic and I understand that one way to do this is self-hosting API inside the windows service. I need to know about other possible implementation possibilities.

Any inputs in this regard are welcome.

Comment: I think self-hosting an API through the Windows Service is the way to go. Might want to check out [How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-windows-service)

Comment: You should consume that service using HttpClient or similar

Comment: @Peter I am trying to learn about any other options of achieving this rather than self-hosting.

Comment: @YuriS I am asking about how to write the part which will be consumed.

Comment: I don't get the question. Do you have your REST service hosted on the machine? If yes what is the API? Do provide you an answer I need to know about your service

Comment: "I have a REST API created using web API" Do you have it or not?

Comment: @YuriS Yes I have the RESTapplication and the windows service ready. What I am planning to do is invoke a method in the windows service from REST app.

Comment: then use httpclient. there are a lot of examples using it. if you make your service publicly accessible and provide your API description I can help you more. It dersn't matter if you call it from windows service or windows app. the code will be the same